# How to exclude htaccess redirect for a subpage (internal page) on a domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, blogger

I have purchased a custom domain with Godaddy that is hosted separately on blogger (google). My domain name example.com (without www) is redirected to www.example.com using htaccess file on Godaddy. I am trying to create a php page on Godaddy economy free hosting as blogger does not support php. All the content will continue to be hosted on blogger. However, I need this php page to display something for my visitors.

Now here is my problem:- When I create a php page/file on godaddy (example:- mottobiz.com/recommends/go), when i put the url path in browser- it redirects to blogger giving me an error saying page does not exist on blogger. I believe this due to the fact that my domain is redirected to blogger. Is there a method or a command in htaccess that will exclude this particular php page from redirecting?

The following is my htaccess redirect code:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it would be something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^myfile\.php` as the third line of your .htaccess. Basically, if someone requests your URL and does NOT request that file, then redirect to Blogger, else it will continue loading that file from Godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
#only requests that do not begin with /recommends/go
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/recommends/go [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

you could also exclude specific files as the comment from `JP` above says

Comment: thanks, I appreciate your help.  Will try out both the suggestions.